# Difference between pm.response.json() and JSON.parse(responseBody)

Tags: javascript, json, postman

What is the fundamental difference between

```
const json_response = pm.response.json()
```

and

```
json_response = JSON.parse(responseBody)
```

Comment: Well... the second one is built-in, while the other one comes with postman

Comment: First: why have you edited my question ? Second: does that mean, that the second can be applied for any environment, while the first only to postman. Correct ?

Comment: Postman's `.json` uses [liquid-json](https://github.com/postmanlabs/liquid-json), which itself uses `JSON.parse` under-the-hood. --- "An implementation of JSON which ignores BOM and shows more detailed error messages on parse failures."

Comment: Is the question about the `pm.response` method vs `JSON.parse`, or about the missing `const`?

Comment: Let me clarify my question. My question was: what is the difference if I use in postman const json_response = pm.response... OR json_response = JSON.parse...

Comment: Yes, that's literally what the asked question was. And the answer is that the major difference is the missing `const` declaration in the second statement

Comment: Understood. Thank you Bergi

Comment: Good question. Somewhat surprising it has not been asked previously. A tip for you, Lexamenrf: since you accepted the answer by Danny Dainton I suppose you are happy with it? If so, the best way to show your gratitude (to "pay him back") is to upvote his answer. (Just click on the up-arrow next to his answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Danny Dainton has already pointed out, `JSON.parse(responseBody)` and
`pm.response.json()` do the same thing - they both return the response body
of your API request as a string in JSON format.

Concerning the *missing `const` declaration in the second statement*. - If you
put the two statements in the same file, then clearly you are correct to
leave out the `const` declaration in the second statement.
(Otherwise there will be a syntax error: `Identifier 'json_response' has already been declared`.)

But since the two statements do the same thing, it makes no sense to have
them both in the same script.
And if they are not in the same script, a declaration is necessary in the
second statement as well as in the first.

Answer (score 5):

In the Postman sandbox context, `JSON.parse(responseBody)` and `pm.response.json()` is doing the same thing.

The `pm.*` API hasn't been in the product the whole time and was introduced to cover lots of different actions that users would normally take when accessing things like, the response body.

Previously, users would use `JSON.parse(responseBody)` in the sandbox environment to get this data.

Here's the full list of the `pm.*` API methods but this can also be seen in the app with the auto-suggestion feature when you type `pm.`

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/

I would personally recommend that you use the `pm.repsonse.json()` method in the app.